# Delay MathJax processing of specific elements

Tags: mathjax

I have a website with simple text, mixed with sections where only the header is visible initially. Clicking the header expands the section. All parts of this page can contain math that I want to be typeset nicely with MathJax, but the sections can be very long and contain a lot of math. **I would like to defer the processing of each section until the corresponding header is clicked.** Is this possible?

I know that MathJax has `TypeSet` functions that I can call when the section is displayed, so dynamically typesetting the math is not the issue. I also found the `elements` configuration option, but this does the opposite of what I want: it lets you only process certain elements, while I want to exclude certain elements.

Example page: http://jsfiddle.net/pnbjh5tg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this. Essentially, I overlooked the `ignoreClass` option of the [tex2jax pre-processor](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/v1.1-latest/options/tex2jax.html). Adding the class `tex2jax_ignore` to all sections makes sure that they are not processed when the page loads. The following JavaScript then processes them when their header is clicked:

```js
var section = $(this).parent().children('.section-container');
section.removeClass("tex2jax_ignore");
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,section.get(0)]);
```

The result can be seen in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4gobsk0/).

Answer (score 2):

In the current MathJax version (`v3.0.1`), you do this by adding

`typeset: false`

in your config script. ([MathJax source code](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-src/blob/1d5ce9837c82f1d12efec8da829c2138bd640c08/ts/components/startup.ts#L54))
You can then run `MathJax.typeset()` from JS when you want to typeset the document.

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pk7mvn3b/) for a demo.

Comment: Thanks, `MathJax.typeset()` is very useful when we want to pre-process HTML before passing to MathJax to typeset them.